# Use the result of one service call (List) to get another List

Tags: scala

I have a service that returns a datatype (`Foo` below) that contains a list of ids to be used for a second service call `getBar` below

```scala
case class Foo(barIds: List[Int])
case class Bar(id: Int)

val f = Future(List(Foo(List(1, 2)), Foo(List(5, 6))))
def getBar(l: List[Int]) = Future(l.map(Bar(_)))
```

What i need is `Future[List[Foo,List[Bar]]]`

I tried first a nested for-comprehension but

```scala
val rr = for {
    foos <- f
} yield  for {
    foo <- foos
    bars <- getBar(foo.barIds) // won't work as this is a Future and foos is a list
} yield (foo,bars)
```

I then played a mapping game, (which smells horrible):

```
f.map(
    foos => foos.map(foo => (foo, foo.barIds)))
        .map(ts => ts.map(t => (t._1, getBar(t._2)))
)
```

But that gives me a `Future[List[Foo,Future[List[Bar]]]]`

There should be way to get `Future[List[Foo,List[Bar]]]` and hopefully in a much cleaner way

Here is a scalafiddle https://scalafiddle.io/sf/P0FRIGs/0

Note the value i am after is: tuples with Foo and a list of "their" associated Bar values:

```
List(
     (Foo(List(1, 2)),List(Bar(1), Bar(2))),
     (Foo(List(5, 6)),List(Bar(5), Bar(6)))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a helper wrapper method around `getBar` that returns the `foo` passed in, and combine that with `Future.traverse` like so:

```
private def getFooAndBars(foo: Foo): Future[(Foo, List[Bar])] =
  getBar(foo.barIds).map(foo -> _)

val res: Future[List[(Foo, List[Bar])]] =
  f.flatMap(Future.traverse(_)(getFooAndBars))
```

`Future.traverse` will take each `foo`, call `getFooAndBars` on it, and flatten the list so that you get a `Future[List]` instead of a `List[Future]`.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping things into required structured can be tricky sometimes, in such cases you can choose your identifiers in a way that these help you navigate the complexity in a more meaningful way. Here you go.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

case class Foo(barIds: List[Int])
case class Bar(id: Int)

def getBar(l: List[Int]) = Future(l.map(Bar(_)))

val fooListFuture = Future(List(Foo(List(1, 2)), Foo(List(5, 6))))

// You want to get
//Future[List[(Foo,List[Bar])]]

val yourRequireFuture = fooListFuture.flatMap(fooList => {
  Future.sequence(fooList.map(foo =>
    getBar(foo.barIds).map(barList => (foo, barList))
  ))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you want your Lists structured, but would something like this do the job?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Success

case class Foo(barIds: List[Int])
case class Bar(id: Int)

val f: Future[List[Foo]] = Future(List(Foo(List(1, 2)), Foo(List(5, 6))))
def getBar(l: List[Int]): Future[List[Bar]] = Future(l.map(Bar(_)))

val bars: Future[List[Bar]] = f.flatMap(x => getBar(x.flatMap(_.barIds)))

val out: Future[List[(Foo, List[Bar])]] = for {
  foo <- f
  bar <- bars
} yield {
  foo.map(x => (x, bar))
}

out andThen {case Success(v)=>println(v)  }

// List((Foo(List(1, 2)),List(Bar(1), Bar(2), Bar(5), Bar(6))), (Foo(List(5, 6)),List(Bar(1), Bar(2), Bar(5), Bar(6))))
```

[[Fiddle]](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/s89LHEH/0)

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't clear about the values. The tuples should be the `Foo` with a list of their associated `Bar` values. So `List[(Foo, List[Bar])] = List((Foo(List(1, 2)),List(Bar(1), Bar(2))), (Foo(List(5, 6)),List(Bar(5), Bar(6))))`

Comment: Ah fair enough. You could do some sort of `.filter` on your `List[Bar]` but honestly the answer @Zoltán gave seems to do the job much more cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

You solution using `map` is correct however `getBar` also returns a future, you get nested future result `Future[List[Foo,Future[List[Bar]]]]`. You have to merge these futures together using `Future.sequence`.

```
val res: Future[List[(Foo,List[Bar])]] = f.flatMap(foos =>
 Future.sequence(
   foos.map(foo =>
     getBar(foo.barIds).map(foo -> _)
   )
  )
)
```

In addition, your `for` loop solution is also valid, but you have to resolve future value additionally.

```
  val res2: Future[List[(Foo,List[Bar])]] = for {
    foos <- f
    foo <- foos
    fbars <- getBar(foo.barIds) // won't work as this is a Future and foos is a list
    bars <- fbars //because fbars is future, you have to resolve its value. bars is resolved future value. 
  } yield (foo,bars)
```

Comment: Thanks, i am however not able to compile the for-comprehension (as it still mixes a collection type with futures, no?

Comment: It should work now(edited), you don't have resolve value in body after yielding it, instead you can resolve it directly and yield final value. Also, for-comprehension will flatten multiple futures into one, so it wont mixes collection type with futures.